# HackerRank Array Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem

Can anybody suggest me what I am doing wrong. This fails to satisfy some of the test cases and shows runtime error. This is my code:

```
   def arrayManipulation(n,m, queries):
    arr=[0]*n
    for i in range(m):
        a=queries[i][0]
        b=queries[i][1]
        k=queries[i][2]
        arr[a-1]+=k
        if(b!=n):
            arr[b]-=k
    actual=0
    maxi=0
    for j in range(n):
        actual+=arr[j]
        if(maxi<actual):
            maxi=actual
        arr[j]=actual        #this line
    return (maxi)
```

But when i remove the above line all the test cases work fine.

Can anybody tell me whats wrong????

Comment: can you show what test cases don't pass and input?

Comment: What is the goal of this exercise? And can you post test input, expected output and actual output for some of the test cases that fail?

Comment: Why does your function take an `m` parameter? The instructions say it takes `n` and `queries`.

Comment: @Jpsh It fails for inputs with large values. Here is a test case: [link](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1636/input11.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1599813187&Signature=siGQGsL%2F%2F8eIo%2BVRFnfHJeuIz5o%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: @MarkMeyer m is the number of operations. It is given as an input in the program. If don't pass it, we can find it inside the function. It is simply len(queries).

Comment: Are you sure that you are following the logic of the exercise? Your tasks do not seem to do what the instructions indicate. Have you posted the correct Hackerrank link?

Comment: @archer Yes ofcourse, it is the correct link. The direct approach to the problem would take a time complexity of O(nm) but that won't solve it. My code has a time complexity of O(n+m)